# How to print array from for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Coding a resume builder. I got stuck on a description section that has to correspond to each school, yet variable to user input (the user determines how many description points for each school). Every time I attempt to print from this loop, I get an error that the variable isn't found. How to fix?

Loop for inputting schools:

```
//numberOfSchools is int entered by user

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSchools; i++) {
        System.out.println("What was school " + (i + 1) + " name?");
        schoolInfo[i][0] = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Where was " + schoolInfo[i][0] + " ?");
        schoolInfo[i][1] = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What was your start date at " + schoolInfo[i][0]);
        schoolInfo[i][2] = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What was your end date at " + schoolInfo[i][0] +
                "enter 'present' if still attending");
        schoolInfo[i][3] = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("How many description points would you like to add for School" + i);
        int eduDescAmount = scan.nextInt();
        String eduDesc[][] = new String[numberOfSchools][eduDescAmount];
        scan.nextLine();
        for(int j = 0; j < eduDescAmount; j++){
            System.out.println("Enter detail " + (j+1) + " for " + schoolInfo[i][0]);
            eduDesc[i][j] = scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
```

Print loop:

```
for (int r = 0; r < schoolInfo.length; r++) {
        for (int q = 0; q < schoolInfo.length; q++){
            System.out.println(eduDesc[r][q]);
        }
```

Comment: What's the issue you're having?

Comment: Need clarification for your question. Unable to understand what you need.

Comment: More code clarification needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eduDesc` is declared each time again in the `for` loop on every iteration. It is also only visible inside the loop. Here is how the correct structure looks like:

```
String[][] eduDesc = new String[numberOfSchools][];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSchools; i++) {
    ...
    int eduDescAmount = scan.nextInt();
    eduDesc[i] = new String[eduDescAmount];
    ...
}
```

Comment: This was the correct solution, worked perfectly! I would upvote but my reputation is low. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `eduDesc` variable is not in scope for the print loop. Every time you open a block, for example, in a method body, in a loop, or in a conditional, you enter an inner scope. This has access to all variables from the outer scope, but anything defined inside it will not be in scope once you exit the block.

Declare the `eduDesc` variable in a scope that is accessible by both loops by declaring it before the first loop, and you will be able to access it.

Comment: Would it be feasible to replace the 'for()' loop with a while loop?

Comment: This won't work because `eduDescAmount` is not known before the loop.

Comment: @EmanuelSaunders If you want to replace the loop, you need to understand why you're doing it. You can have the same behaviour with a while loop, but you still need the eduDesc variable in the outer scope (either at class level or within a method that does both loops).
Since you have a predetermined amount of iterations, for is still the better choice here.

Comment: I was hoping there'd be an alternative method in which I could ask for the 'edu desc' to be defined by the user in the loop, after the questions. Seems not to be the case.

Comment: If you want to define eduDesc within the loop and still use it, you need to do the printing from within the first loop as well so eduDesc is in scope for the printing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem lies in the scope of your `eduDesc` variable. When you write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSchools; i++) {
    /* Your Code */
    int eduDescAmount = scan.nextInt();
    String eduDesc[][] = new String[numberOfSchools][eduDescAmount]; // This means eduDesc[][] is declared as a local variable
    /* More code */
}
```

By a local variable I mean a variable whose scope is limited within the scope in which it is defined. In your case, the variable `eduDesc[][]` is declared within a `for` loop which means it'll only be accessible within the for loop.
As soon as the JVM completes execution of the for loop the variable `eduDesc[][]` is no longer accessible, so if any code outside the loop when tries to access the variable the compiler complains, " Whoa! That variable is declared in a scope of a for loop, its local only to that block!!".

Solution is to declare it outside your loop like:

```
int numberOfSchools = `some int`;
String eduDesc[][] = new String[numberOfSchools][]; 
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSchools; i++) {
    /* n No of schooling work */
    eduDescAmount = scan.nextInt();
    /* More schooling here */
}
```

Hope this answers.

Comment: Same problem as the other answer, `eduDescAmount` is not known before the loop.

Comment: Useful, yet I need to ask for the amount of description points after asking all of the other questions, and have them posed with each school. 
i.e.
information about school 1:
x, y, z;
user wants to add 2 details: 
(user input) (user input) 

School 2: 
x,y, z; 
user wants to add 1 detail:
(user input)


Suggestions?

Comment: Take value for `numberOfSchools` and `eduDescAmount` before entering the for loop and assign it before declaring your `eduDesc[][]` variable, then there shouldn't be any problem.